# How to get XML from WebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8, stream, webrequest

I'm trying to use the following code to get XML data from an URL:

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url);
using (WebResponse webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDoc.Load(webResponse); ////error
    }
}
```

Visual Studio does not accept "XMLDoc.Load()" neither "XMLDoc.LoadXml()" - So, how can I get a xmldoc from webrequest?
Thanks

Comment: No need for `WebRequest`. Just try **`XDocument.Load(url)`**

Comment: `XmlDoc.Load(webResponse);` should probably be `XmlDoc.Load(responseStream);`

Comment: @L.B - Problem is, that there is no *.xml I try fetching a page which delivers the XML in Output.

Comment: @nick_w - No difference. He doesn't like the Load :/

Comment: Really? What error message do you get?

Comment: _missing a using directive or an assembly reference?_ . No Definition for "Load" in Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument;

Comment: @malte `XDocument.Load("http://WhyDontYouTry.com")` see the **`url`** in my comment. I didn't write `XDocument.Load(filename)`

Comment: Okay, showing up the same issue, VisualStudio doesn't know the _Load_! 
Does XDoc.Load(URL) really get the content of the target of the URL? Even if it's not directly *.xml ?

Comment: @malte it is Linq2Xml and What I use is **XDocument** class **not XmlDocument**. And yes it loads the xml from a given url directly.

Comment: @L.B - Wow! Just magic happened and the whole damned thing is working! - Thanks! I just overread the difference between XDocument and XmlDocument!

Comment: I think it might have also been because you are using the `XmlDocument` from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument.aspx) and not the one in `System.Xml` - I guess I missed the windows-8 tag.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
string url = @"http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.getevents&location=" + ub.Ciudad + "&page=1&api_key=" + LAST_API_KEY; //for example
XmlDocument xDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(new Uri(url)); //this does the web request
```

Comment: That works as long as you don't have to edit the header.  A lot of API need you to edit the header these days.